# Generate dynamic image by parameter width - height

Tags: php, image

I'm looking for a way to or php plugin create (generate) a dynamic image
So that the image is brought in a variable size

Do not modify the original image Or save new copies

for example

http://xxxxxxxx/imagename.jpg?width=120

return my new image with new size

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of script who can to that. Many use [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).

If you really want the image name in the URL with a parameter as size you have to rewrite that image name and path to php then resize it and deliver the image. But that then you should implement a caching otherwise you render the image every time you load the image.

Comment: first  Thanks for the answer - Does this bring me this result ؟ https://s3.tmimgcdn.com/templates/1289/scr/presentational-images2.jpg?width=120